# Ghostscript ignores -dDownScaleFactor?

Tags: ghostscript

It seems like Ghostscript is ignoring the `-dDownScaleFactor` argument. Running [the example](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#PNG) both with and without `-dDownScaleFactor` produces identical files:

```
$ gs --version
9.00
$ gs -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -dDownScaleFactor=3 -o with-downscale.png input.pdf
…
$ gs -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -o without-downscale.png input.pdf
…
$ md5 *.png
MD5 (with-downscale.png) = 5480f478ce3486c3fb104c82c4cbd370
MD5 (without-downscale.png) = 5480f478ce3486c3fb104c82c4cbd370
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The png16m device did not support -dDownScaleFactor in ghostscript 9.00. Try updating to 9.10.

Robin